# Save drop-down list value to database in Struts 2 with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, validation, struts2

I want to save the selected value of drop-down list into the database.

First `index.jsp` is loaded. From `index.jsp`, we can go to `register.jsp` when we click register URL of `index.jsp`.

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<action name="registerAction" class="action.RegisterAction" method="populateSelect">
        <result name="success" >register.jsp</result>
     
    </action>
    <action name="register" class="action.RegisterAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success" >login.jsp</result>

    </action>
```

**`index.jsp`:**

```jsp
  <s:url id="url" action="registerAction">
</s:url>
  <s:a href="%{url}">Register</s:a>
```

**`register.jsp`:**

```jsp
   <s:form action="registerAction" method="execute">
     <s:select label="Select Date of Month" key="Month List" name="months" headerKey="0" headerValue="--Select--" list="allMonths" listKey="id" listValue="name"/>
 <s:submit value="Register"/>
 </s:form>
```

**Action class is:**

```java
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport {

    String name, pwd, email, address, months;

    int phno;

    
    List<Month> allMonths = new ArrayList<Month>();
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    UserDao udao = new UserDao();


public List<Month> getAllMonths() {
    return allMonths;
}

public void setAllMonths(List<Month> allMonths) {
    this.allMonths = allMonths;
}

public String getMonths() {
    return months;
}

public void setMonths(String months) {
    this.months = months;
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}


public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPhno() {
    return phno;
}

public void setPhno(int phno) {
    this.phno = phno;
}

public String getPwd() {
    return pwd;
}

public void setPwd(String pwd) {
    this.pwd = pwd;
}

    public RegisterAction() {
    }
    

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        User u = new User();
        u.setName(name);
        u.setEmail(email);
        u.setAddress(address);
        u.setPhno(phno);
        u.setPwd(pwd);
        System.out.println("Hi der "+months);

        u.setMonths(months);
        udao.addUser(u);
        return "success";
    }

    public String listAllUsers() {
        users = udao.getUsers();
        System.out.println("In Action, " + users);
        return "success";
    }


    public String populateSelect() {
        allMonths = udao.getMonths();
        System.out.println("In constructor " + allMonths);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

the drop down list is actually only one of the form fields. there are other fields also in the form.

All values other than month field can be entered into database. for month field, the value being entered is `null`.

I think the value of drop-down is not being taken.

Comment: What's in the logs? What's the mapping for `User.months`? Is it printing the value correctly in your `println`? Is there any validation?

Comment: there is no validation. nthng is being printed in the console. i have changed the code as indicated above. with the above code value is being entered into database , but the value of months is null.

Comment: Is there a public setter for `months` in the action? Have you verified that a `months` value is being sent in the request, e.g., in your JS/network console?

Comment: "Hi der" mentioned along with the System.out.println in being printed in the console..But the value of months is not displayed.

Comment: there is setter for months in action..

Comment: You'll need to provide an [SSCCE](sscce.org) on github or similar to look at. Please verify what's being sent in the request as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change the `months` member variable to a `Map` like this:

```
private Map<Integer, String> months = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Then, implement the `Preparable` interface in you action, and initialize the map with something like this:

```
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    String[] monthNames = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
    int i = 1;
    for (String monthName : monthNames) {
        months.put(i++, monthName);
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to add a getter and a setter for `months`

Also, add an `private Integer month` member variable in your action, that will hold the selected month by the user (again, with getters and setters)

Then, use the following `s:select` tag in your JSP:

```
<s:select label="Select Date of Month" name="month" headerKey="0"
          headerValue="--Select--" list="months"/>
```

So now in your `execute` method, the month member variable should hold the selected month. 0 should be no selection, 1 should be January, etc.

Comment: this method works..can i ask that whether it is possible to do same by using list?without using map?

Comment: I think you can use a list if it contains custom objects, and you should set the `listKey` and `listValue` attributes in the `s:select` tag. But why should you create a separate object for months? It's not that month names will change any time soon :-)

Comment: I used months object as I want to retrieve the months name & id from tbl_mnth in database & populate the s:select with months name..but i want the selected months id to be saved into database..not the selected months name..I am able to save id to database by using the method you specified..but my question is can i do the same by using list.

Comment: So, what the list can't be used to get the months?

Comment: You can use a list, the error in the initial markup of the `s:select` is that you should not add a `key` attribute.

Comment: Why should not add a key attribute? Can't we use a `key` attribute in the `select` tag or what?

Comment: You are right, key does not have to do anything with your problem, sorry. To tell you the truth, I don't know why a list does not work for you, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

In the `index.jsp` just use the code that redirect to the register page

```
<% response.sendRedirect("registerAction.action"); %>
```

in the `register.jsp` the form is mapped to `registerAction` via the form `action` attribute. the action mapping should be

```
<action name="registerAction" class="action.RegisterAction" >
  <result name="success">register.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="register" class="action.RegisterAction" method="register">
  <result name="input">register.jsp</result>
  <result name="success">login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

this mapping is changed to `register` method of the action class which is used in your code to insert a new used with supplied `months` value that should be populated before the action is executed. The `input` result is used where the form tag in the JSP. The `login.jsp` is unknown but it it will be used as a result of the `register` action. The form is also should rename

```
<s:form action="register">
  <s:select label="Select Date of Month" key="Month List" name="months" headerKey="0" headerValue="--Select--" list="allMonths" listKey="id" listValue="name"/>
  <s:submit value="Register"/>
</s:form>
```

the code of the action changes

```
private String months;
//public getter and setter of months

public String register() throws Exception {
    User u = new User();
    u.setName(name);
    u.setEmail(email);
    u.setAddress(address);
    u.setPhno(phno);
    u.setPwd(pwd);
    System.out.println(months);

    u.setMonths(months);
    udao.addUser(u);
    return "success";
}

private List<Month> allMonths;
//public getter and setter of allMonths
```

assumed that the action class implement `Preparable`, better do it at once here because the list could be used if the validation (if any) fails.

```
public void prepare() throws Exception {
   //populate allMonths 
   //and set the value of months if you want it to be preselected.
}
```

and the action should extend the `ActionSupport` that have the `execute` method already implemented.

Comment: I am using populateSelect to populate the drop downlist.
I havent used preparable interface.

I haveupdated the question with my current code..

Comment: Result `"none"` is a reserved name for `Action.NONE`. This means no  action result should be executed. Use another name `"success"` or `Action.SUCCESS` for example.

Comment: still the month field value is null

Comment: you are commented getters and setters, so it should populate it if you have both.

Comment: yes. the value month should be retrieved..dont no why it is not being retrieved..

Comment: because there's no getters and setters, only comments in the code. This comments you should use to code the actual getters and setters.

Comment: i editted the action class to include the getters setters. see above action class..