# Struts2 select tag - Dynamically add options

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I'm working on migrating a Struts1 project to Struts2. And I have encountered the following piece of code.

```jsp
<html:select ...>
  <logic:iterate id="something" name="" type="">
    <logic:equal name="something" property="" value="">
      <html:option value=""><bean:write ... /></html:option>
    </logic:equal>
  </logic:iterate>
</html:select>
```

It checks the value in the iterator and add options to the select list dynamically if the condition is met.

How can I achieve something similar with Struts2 select tag.

AFAIK, Struts2 select tag won't even work properly with plain html option tag.

Comment: You don't need logical operations with select tag, just move the logic to the action.

Comment: @RomanC Without moving the logic, is there a way to do it though?

Comment: You can do it but without select tag.

Comment: Please put the conditions (even fake, but similar to yours) in the tags, then I'll answer

Comment: @AndreaLigios i dont see why u need them to answer the question.

Comment: I've adopted the solution that @RomanC mentioned. I moved all the logic handling to the action class. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed Struts2 `<s:select>` tag doesn't allow to use html `option` tags in the body of the tag. This is because it's using `list` attribute to provide data in  the form of an object with key/value pairs. You can use `listKey` and `listValue` to define which properties of the object will be used for rendering options. You can see UI Tags Reference Guide for [`<s:select>`](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) tag. It has many attributes that allows you to customize rendering HTML.

Practical usage of the select tag: it's rarely used. It's useful if you want to show fixed size lists or a map created via OGNL in the JSP.

For example:

```xml
<s:select label="Months"
       name="months"
       headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Month"
       list="#{'01':'Jan', '02':'Feb', [...]}"
       value="selectedMonth"
       required="true"
/>
```

---

For big lists consider to use an [`<sj:autocompleter>`](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag) widget. You can also use an autocompleter as select box or select widget as autocompleter. All examples of `select` and `autocompleter` widgets you can see in [Struts2 Jquery Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action).

When migrating from Struts1 to Struts2 you have faced with the problem of presenting rendered html `select` tag because Struts2 doesn't allow options inside the body of the tag. So constructing the list of options could be made in the `prepare()` method of the action. An example of this usecase you can find via reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992032/573032).

Why this approach is preferable because you are **working with the model from the controller**, not from the view, and when the model *is ready* to display you are using some tags or widgets to render html or populate DOM. Or you can use Ajax or Angular services to load a model from the Struts2 controller. The data is transferred in the JSON format. JSON is very powerful tool to transfer data between Java and JavaScript frameworks.

---

Now if you still want to use the map to render the html `select` tag via the iterator, you can use the following code.

```xml
<select id="monthId" name="form.monthId">
  <s:iterator var="month" value="%{months}">
    <s:if test="month.value != 'May'">
      <option value="${month.key}" ${month.key == form.monthId?'selected="selected"':''}>
        <s:property value="%{month.value}"/>
      </option>
    </s:if>
   </s:iterator>
</select>
```

---

Note,  that EL expressions used to pre-select the options should have access to valueStack variables due to Struts request wrapper. See [How we use JSTL with the framework](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Can+we+use+JSTL+with+the+framework).