# Using OGNL inside a JSP scripting delimiters

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator, ognl

How can I use the OGNL inside a scripting delimiters?

```xml
<s:iterator var="arr" value="%{carNames}" status="incr">        
    <option value="<%=car.getType()["#incr.index"]%>" >
        <s:property value="arr"/>
    </option>           
</s:iterator>
```

This is my `Car` structure:

```java
private String[] carNames = {"A", "B", "C"};

public static Integer[] getType() {
    return new Integer[]{
        new Integer(Global.DISEL),
        new Integer(Global.TESLA),
        new Integer(Global.HYBRID)
    };
 }

 //getter and setter
```

Comment: Post your Java structure (carNames)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scripting delimiters you can't use OGNL. You should remove scriptlets an replace it with `<s:property>` tag or use `${}`.

```jsp
<option value="<s:property value='%{car.type[#incr.index]}'/>">
```

It shows how to use [OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl.html) in HTML tags.

If you are working with select tag, I recommend you to read [Struts2 select tag - Dynamically add options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483141/573032).

Answer (score 1):

In the Java structure you have there's no correlation between the list of car names and the list of types. They're unrelated, and hence is not clear how to bind them together.

You should use JavaBeans convention and create a Car class, like

```java
public class Car implements Serializable {
    @Getter @Setter private Long    id;
    @Getter @Setter private String  name;
    @Getter @Setter private Integer type; // but an Enum would be better
}
```

and then declare an array

```java
@Getter private Car[] cars;
```

or a List

```java
@Getter private List<Car> cars;
```

in the action, and then the code would be:

```xml
<select name="selectedCar"> 
<s:iterator value="cars" status="incr">        
    <option value="<s:property value='cars[%{#incr.index%}].id'/>" >
        <s:property value="cars[%{#incr.index%}].type"/> - 
        <s:property value="cars[%{#incr.index%}].name"/>
    </option>           
</s:iterator>
</select>
```

which is equivalent to

```xml
<select name="selectedCar"> 
<s:iterator var="currentCar" value="cars" >        
    <option value="<s:property value='#currentCar.id'/>" >
        <s:property value='#currentCar.type'/> -
        <s:property value="#currentCar.name"/>
    </option>           
</s:iterator>
</select>
```

which is equivalent to

```xml
<select name="selectedCar"> 
<s:iterator value="cars" >        
    <option value="<s:property value='id'/>" >
        <s:property value="type"/> -
        <s:property value="name"/>
    </option>           
</s:iterator>
</select>
```

which is equivalent to

```xml
<select name="selectedCar"> 
<s:iterator value="cars" >        
    <option value="<s:property value='id'/>" >
        <s:property value="%{type + ' - ' + name}"/>
    </option>           
</s:iterator>
</select>
```

But it would be simpler to use the `<s:select />` Struts tag with:

```xml
<s:select name="selectedCar" 
          list="cars" 
       listKey="id" 
     listValue="%{type + ' - ' + name}" />
```

and no iterators at all.

To read the selected Car you simply need to put a Car and a setter in the target action:

```java
@Setter private Car selectedCar;
```