# How to make mutex checkbox in Struts2?

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I have a variable `paramMap`, the type is `HashMap<String, String>`, which has two elements:

```
{"1", "areaNo"}
{"2", "areaOrgNo"}
```

and the checkbox code of Struts2 is as follows:

```
<s:iterator value="paramMap" var="params" status="paramStatus">
  <input type="checkbox" name="params" key_id="#paramStatus.index" value="<s:property value="#param.key"/>"
  <s:if test="#paramStatus.index=0">
    onclick=checkAreaNo()
  </s:if>
```

The logic I want is when I check `areaNo`, `areaOrgNo` will be unchecked, how should I write the function `checkAreaNo()` within the `<script></script>`? I have written `checkAreaNo()` as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
  function checkAreaNo() {
    if ( $(input[key_id='1']).prop("checked") ) {
      $(input[key_id='1']).prop("checked", false)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this solves it, thanks.

Comment: It's interesting that in the `<input>` tag you do it correctly for the `value` property, but not for the `key_id` property. Sometimes it's just a matter of taking a step back and looking at what you're already doing to find the answer for something else you'd like to do.

Comment: @Min I have converted my comment into the answer, see below. And if it solves your problem, then mark a upper triangle with the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what elements are in your map, but in plain HTML elements are DOM and you can't use OGNL syntax with them. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773827/573032) answer for details.

So, as I said in the commented answer to use OGNL to the plain html tag you should use [`<s:property>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/property-tag.html) or JSP EL.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="params" key_id="<s:property value='#paramStatus.index'/>" value="<s:property value='#params.key'/>" label="<s:property value='#params.value'/>">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="params" key_id="${paramStatus.index}" value="${params.key}" label="${params.value}">
```