# Struts2 - s:select tag Value attribute not returning anything inside display tag

Tags: struts2

We are converting from struts 1 to struts 2. As part of it. we have a list in the DB where we need to display as the drop down with diff value selected in the drop down in each row. Eg

If list contains cat,dog, cow

then Row 1 in display tag should display dropdown with all the 3 values selected with option "cat"

then Row 2 in display tag should display dropdown with all the 3 values selected with option "dog"

similarly remaining.

I am able to get the dropdowns but unable to pre select the dropdown

In struts 1 we have the code like this (working code)

```
<display:table name="requestScope.channelList" 
            requestURI="/channels.do?method=search" uid="channel">

<display:column title="Channel">
<html:select property="channelCdUpd" value="${channel.channelCd}">
<html:option value="${channel.channelCd}">${channel.channelCd}</html:option>
<html:optionsCollection property="allChannels"/>
</html:select>
</display:column>
```

Struts 2 my code is like this  (new code)

```
 <display:table name="requestScope.dfSrcLocChannelList" 
                requestURI="channelsSearch.action" uid="channel"> 
<display:column title="Channel">
    <s:select value="???????"
    headerKey="" headerValue=""
    name="channelCdUpd" list="allChannels" />
 </display:column>
</display:table>
```

This value inside select is where I am struggling to populate correctly as struts2 doesnt support this ${}
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Mh, so the your problem is how used expression language into struts2 right? if yes, try to use this code `<s:property value="%{#rowStatus.index}"/>`,struts2 used OGNL this is an [reference](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-ognl-expression-language-example-1.html)

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo You'd need an iterator for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37483141/573032

Answer (score 0):

struts uses %{...}  expression. it is called ognl
value="%{...}"

```
<s:select label="label blabla"
 name="bean.anyproperty"                      
 list="%{listBean}" listKey="anyproperty"  listValue="anyproperty" 
value="{bean.property}">
</s:select>
```